# Creating a presigned POST URL for file upload with AWS SDK for PHP v2

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to set up an upload process on a rather old web server so that when a user uploads a new file to it, the client first sends a request (without the file) to the web server, which does some processing and returns a pre-signed URL which will allow the client to upload the file directly to S3.

It should be noted that I'm using v2 of the AWS SDK for PHP due to the version of PHP installed on the server.

I'm able to create the presigned URL using the following code:

```
$s3Client = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    'secret' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
));

$command = $s3Client->getCommand('PutObject', array(
    'Bucket' => 'bucketname',
    'Key' => $this->_id.'/model.xyz',
    'Body' => '',
    'ContentMD5' => false,
    'ContentType' => 'multipart/form-data',
));

return $command->createPresignedUrl('+20 minutes');
```

This successfully creates a URL, which is passed to the client. However, upon sending the subsequent request to S3, I get this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
    <AWSAccessKeyId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</AWSAccessKeyId>
    <StringToSign>POST

    multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryLFAYOUC0JsblZJHj
    1464614702
    /bucketname/blah/model.xyz</StringToSign>
    <SignatureProvided>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</SignatureProvided>
    <StringToSignBytes>xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx...</StringToSignBytes>
    <RequestId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</RequestId>
    <HostId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</HostId>
</Error>
```

I have just created the access and secret keys used (with a user with more than enough permissions), so incorrect keys are not the issue.

Request headers:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:50145
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryLFAYOUC0JsblZJHj
Host:bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com
Origin:http://website.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://website.com/script.php
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
```

The content lengths indicated here are different, but is this important? Given that the URL is generated before the file is uploaded, I'm unsure how I would get that information anyway.

If anyone can see anything obviously wrong with the above that would cause this failure, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a pre-signed `PUT` URL for a `POST` upload.

You use a signed policy document (base64-encoded JSON describing the permissible attributes of the upload), a signature, and some other attributes, like the content-type of the actual file, all embedded in a form.

For Signature Version 2, the construction of the policy, signature, and form are described at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html.

For Signature Version 4, the same information is at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-authentication-HTTPPOST.html.

Note that "signature version" is not related to SDK version.  All regions support Sig V4.  Regions launched before 2014 also support Sig V2 which is somewhat easier to implement from scratch.

I mention that, because I don't see this mentioned at all in the docs for the PHP V2 SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm currently struggling with how to actually get all the information required for the request from the SDK - do you have any suggestions here?

Comment: I'm not sure that this particular SDK will be much help.  I have always written all my own code for request signing, policy generation, etc.  Not a PHP person, though.